# NSErrorDomain for packaging a HTTP result code?

Tags: ios, http-status-codes, nserror

There is `NSPOSIXErrorDomain` for packaging posix errors, `NSOSStatusErrorDomain` for packaging Carbon errors, etc, etc.

Is there a standard domain for packaging an HTTP status code as an error?

```
id error = [NSError errorWithDomain: @"HTTP"
                               code: 404
                           userInfo: theInfo];
```

I know I could create my own error domain constant just by specifying my own string there, but that seems the wrong way to handle this. Surely there's a domain intended for this specific purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interests of closing this, I'm going to just declare that there isn't. If someone knows of a way, feel free to post another answer and I'll select it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've used exactly the same domain (`@"HTTP"`).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `NSURLErrorDomain` for that purpose.

Comment: [Apple lists the available error codes here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes?language=objc)